# What are the fixed-points of the Y combinator?

Tags: recursion, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic, fixed-point

Since the Y combinator itself is a function (albeit a higher-order one), I was wondering what the fixed-points of Y itself are.

Answer (score 1):

$U = λxλy·y(xy)$ is the fixed point of $Y$ and $Y$ is the fixed point of $U$.

How, and in what sense, I describe here:
[Equality Of (Infinitary) Lambda Terms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138768/equality-of-lambda-terms-which-do-not-have-normal-form/167344#167344).